# Regex to filter contact numbers

Tags: java, regex

I've a list of phone numbers, but want to remove some of them on basis of some condition. I'm trying to set up in ETL.

Let's say this is the list of contact numbers:

```
897-54-6212
985566655
568-00-9977
000-56-8795
875-95-9999
&^*-(&-#$@)
111-85-4568
222-56-6542
333-56-4589
444-48-8978
555-48-8978
666-58-5648
777-58-5647
888-86-8978
456-33-5685
485-44-4568
465-55-8523
485-66-7824
468-77-5948
854-88-2358
785-78-1111
588-64-2222
078-05-1120
455-56-(0000)
```

And I don't want numbers like if it contains:

1. The first three digits should not contains 000 or 666 or 900 or 999 (for example 666-77-5948 should be rejected)
2. Number should also be rejected if it contains 00 in between (for example 945-00-8796)
3. If number contains any kind of special character like `@!#$%^()`

Is that possible kind of some regex so that I could filter kind of these records. I've tried with substrings function but that's didn't work as expected.

These number should be rejected:

```
985566655
568-00-9977
000-56-8795
&^*-(&-#$@)
666-58-5648
455-56-(0000)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: To be clear, can you indicate which numbers are invalid in that list?

Comment: What regex flavor?

Comment: @4castle, dwag ...question updated.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? As in what programming language is this used by? Different engines have different features.

Comment: @4castle..I'm trying to do this in ETL. with java language

Comment: I've always kept this page bookmarked to help w/ regex: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special characters can be ruled out by using a regex that specifies only numbers and dashes:

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

If you add on negative lookbehinds to blacklist certain numbers, it would look like this:

```
^\d{3}(?<!000|666|999|900)-\d{2}(?<!00)-\d{4}$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ8sA7/4)

Since you will be matching this against a list, make sure to precompile the regex using a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) object. Don't use [`String#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) in a loop.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...
Pattern phone = Pattern.compile("^\\d{3}(?<!000|666|999|900)-\\d{2}(?<!00)-\\d{4}$");
...
boolean isValid = phone.matcher(inputString).matches();
```

Comment: @4castle...What d is here ?

Comment: In Java, you have to escape backslashes in string literals. You will have to add an extra backslash to all the backslashes in the regex. `\d` means "digit" in regex. As a string literal it becomes `\\d`.

Comment: @Kate I've added a snippet of code to show how to use it.

Comment: @4castle...is that possible I could add something to define range in first condition...so that number from between  900 to 999 also could gets rejected ?

Comment: That's actually pretty easy. Just blacklist `9` as a first character. The first negative lookhehind will become: `(?<!000|666|9..)`