# Verify code format in Java

Tags: java, validation, numbers, match

I'm working on a project for school in which we must verify the format of a code. The format is 3 capital letters followed by 3 digits where at least 1 digit is not a 0. So ABC001 is valid. ABC000 is not valid.

Where I'm stuck is how I'd write the format to validate the digits so that 000 is invalid while 001-999 is valid. Below is the code, it's currently written so that 000 is valid.

```
public static boolean validateInvoiceCode(String invoiceCode)
{
      return invoiceCode.matches("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` that blacklists `000`:

```
[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9](?<!000)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ8dX6/1)

You may also want to improve your regex by using quantifiers, and `\d` for digits:

```
[A-Z]{3}\\d{3}(?<!000)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ8tQ9/1)

Comment: Any reason you chose a lookbehind over a lookahead? Just curious.

Comment: @shmosel That way it fails earlier if the input doesn't have digits at all. It's more useful when the blacklist has more than one input to reject, like in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38841776/5743988).